# How to test custom angular HTML input with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having problems unit testing an angular component. Normally angular components are placed on the page like so: `<custom-input/>` and you have an HTML template: `template: '<input/>'` but for my purposes I am placing the selector in brackets: `selector:'[custom-input]'` and using the component on the page like this: `<input custom-input/>` . The problem I am having is when testing in Jasmine the rendered component is a `<div>` and not an `<input/>` . Is there a way to have Jasmine compile the component as an HTML input and not a div?

UPDATE:

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: '[prps-text]',
  template:`
  `,
})
export class PrpsTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() size: string = '';
  @Input() maxlength: string = '';
  @Input() property: string = '';
  @Input() readonly: string = '';
  @Input() styleClass: string = '';

  @HostBinding('attr.type') inputType: string = 'text'
  @HostBinding('attr.name') inputName: string = ''
  @HostBinding('attr.maxlength') inputMaxLength: string = ''
  @HostBinding('attr.size') inputSize: string = ''
  @HostBinding('attr.value') inputValue: string = ''
  @HostBinding('attr.readonly') isReadOnly: string | null = null;
  @HostBinding('attr.class') class: string = '';
  
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.property != ''){
      this.inputName = this.property
    }
    if(this.maxlength != ''){
      this.inputMaxLength = this.maxlength
    }
    if(this.size != ''){
      this.inputSize = this.size
    }
    if (this.readonly === 'true') {
      this.isReadOnly = ''
    }
    if(this.styleClass != ''){
      this.class = this.styleClass
    }
  }

}
```

app-component.html

```
<input prps-text type="text"/>
```

spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PrpsTextComponent } from './prps-text.component';

describe('PrpsTextComponent', () => {
  let component: PrpsTextComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PrpsTextComponent>;
  let compiled: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PrpsTextComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PrpsTextComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should create with type attribute text', () => {
    expect(compiled.getAttribute('type')).toEqual('text')
  })

  it('should set name attribute when property has value', () => {
    component.property = "organization"

    component.ngOnInit()
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.property).toBe('organization')
    expect(component.inputName).toBe('organization')
    expect(compiled.getAttribute('name')).toEqual('organization');
  })

  it('should set maxlength attribute', () => {
    component.maxlength = '3'
    
    component.ngOnInit()
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.maxlength).toBe('3')
    expect(component.inputMaxLength).toBe('3');
    expect(compiled.getAttribute('maxlength')).toBe('3')
  })

  it('should set size attribute', () => {
    component.size = '3'

    component.ngOnInit()
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.size).toBe('3')
    expect(component.inputSize).toBe('3')
    expect(compiled.getAttribute('size')).toBe('3')
  })

  it('should set to readonly', () => {
    component.readonly = 'true'

    component.ngOnInit()
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.readonly).toBe('true')
    expect(component.isReadOnly).toBeTrue
    expect(compiled.getAttribute('readonly')).toBeTrue
  })

  it('should set styleClass', () => {
    component.styleClass = 'input_disabled'

    component.ngOnInit()
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.styleClass).toBe('input_disabled')
    expect(component.class).toBe('input_disabled')
    expect(compiled.getAttribute('class')).toBe('input_disabled')
  })
});
```

My component has no template since the component isn't technically a component but an element with customized behavioral attributes so when the component is compiled by the test it renders like this: `<div id="root66" ng-version="11.0.9"></div>` instead of like this: `<input id="root66" ng-version="11.0.9"/>`. I can't test a div like an input and that is the problem I am trying to solve. The question would be: is there any way to mock the component as an input rather than a div so I can test the functionality correctly?

Comment: Hi. Can you show us some code of how you are doing your test please ? Thanks

Comment: hey @MattewEon. I updated the post with the code i'm using to define the component. there is no html template for this component. I'm using it as an HTMLInputElement on the app-component html. When testing the component renders itself as a div element and not an input since so there are some aspects of testing this component that can't be done like testing for maxlength.

Comment: If i were to set the components maxlength to 3 and give it a value that has 4 characters I would want to check that the displayed input would only show 3 characters. I was wondering if there was a way to mock the component with the <input prps-text/> or configure the test to render it as an HTMLInputElement.

Comment: You probably have a testing file too with Jasmine ? Can we have a look at it ?

Comment: @MattewEon I updated the post with the spec.ts and further explanation of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a component with an attribute selector or a directive, you have to encapsulate it in another component. Here is an example :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'prps-text-test',
  template:`<div [prps-text]></div>
  `,
})
export class PrpsTextTestComponent {}

describe('PrpsTextComponent', () => {
  let component: PrpsTextTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PrpsTextTestComponent>;
  let compiled: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PrpsTextComponent, PrpsTextTestComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

 [...]
});
```